# How can I get a queryParams from react to node.j s

Tags: node.js

Currently, I'm trying to use oAuth service so I needed to get the params from website and i need to give this params Info to Backend, So, I tried to pass it by using `fetch` from react.js,
However, I get the empty object in backend , i want to know how I can get the params and what make it empty .
Thank you in advance
Here is my code :

### client:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/create", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(code),
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log("parsed json", json);
      })
      .catch(ex => {});
  });
```

### server:

`app.post("/create", function (req, res) { console.log(req.body); });`

Answer (score 0):

```
GET /something?color1=red&color2=blue

app.get('/something', (req, res) => {
    req.query.color1 === 'red'  // true
    req.query.color2 === 'blue' // true
})



// GET /search?q=tobi+ferret
console.dir(req.query.q)
// => 'tobi ferret'

// GET /shoes?order=desc&shoe[color]=blue&shoe[type]=converse
console.dir(req.query.order)
// => 'desc'

console.dir(req.query.shoe.color)
// => 'blue'

console.dir(req.query.shoe.type)
// => 'converse'

// GET /shoes?color[]=blue&color[]=black&color[]=red
console.dir(req.query.color)
// => ['blue', 'black', 'red']


I hope this may help you.**strong text**
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use express body-parser middleware.

```
app.use(express.json());
```